# What does CTR mean in CatBoost

Tags: machine-learning, catboost

The acronym "CTR" is frequently used in CatBoost https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic.html to represent a type of value.  But I couldn't find what the acronym stands for.  Could you please spell out the non acronym form, and provide some references to its definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctr is an acronym of **click-through rate**. They encode categorically features using this metric to get better results. It is quite similar to mean encoding.

*I didn't get any online resource for reference.*

Comment: That's weird.  Spelling out one of the equations in doc "Click through rate_[i] = (countInClass + prior) / (totalCount + 1)" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, but I am pretty sure it's some form of encoding as, at the end of the documentation, they called the same formula as avg_target.

Answer (score 0):

**Click Through Rate** which is commonly used in advertisement industry. CatBoost was created by Yandex which makes all the profits in ads so I am not surprised they used CTR metric as an example all over documentation.

Comment: Could you please clarify what does click through rate have anything to do with transforming categorical feature to numerical feature?  I felt like it's "categorical to response" or "categorical to real number", but can not be sure about it.

Comment: if I understand it right, it's a form of target encoding. but yes they could have chose a more generic name for that feature.